# How to check via two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, xml-parsing

I have a stored procedure with some input parameters including an XML parameter. I have a situation that I need to use one of the input fields coming directly and also another column of the XML input for looping through and check in the respective different tables. Example below.

```
Procedure A
@ID varchar
@xml XML
```

I have two tables TableA, TableB.

```
TableA contains ID.
TableB contains @xml's fields named X,Y.
```

Now I need to write my logic in my SP as

1. if TableA contains ID then update it or else create a new ID as per input value.
2. Check tableB for value X in @XML, if it exists, then update it, else write a new value.
3. Write a small temptable for storing the values of XML (i.e X,Y) values and use it's values for checking.

Please help me with this construct. I will develop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketch:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[procedure_name]
    @ID  VARCHAR(100)
   ,@xml XML
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

/* Write a small temptable for storing the values of XML (i.e X,Y)
   values and use it's values for checking */
CREATE TABLE #temp(col_1 INT
                  ,col_2 NVARCHAR(100)
                  (...)   
             );

INSERT INTO #temp(col_1, col_2, ...)
SELECT 
   [col_1] = col.value('col_name[1]','INT'),
   [col_2] = col.value('col_name[2]', 'NVARCHAR(100)')
FROM @xml.value('/node') AS T(col);

/* if TableA contains ID then update it or else create a new ID
  as per input value */
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableA WHERE ID = @ID)
    UPDATE tabA
    SET col_1 = ....
    FROM TableA A
    WHERE ID = @ID
ELSE
   INSERT INTO TableA(col_1, col_2, ...)
   SELECT col_1, ...
   FROM #temp

/* Check tableB for value X in @XML, if it exists, then update it,
   else write a new value.  */

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM TableB tab_b
           JOIN #temp t
              ON tab_b.id = t.id)
BEGIN
    -- Update here
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   -- Insert here
END


END
```

Comment: Thank you very much, with tortoise speed, I reached myself upto XML checking. I was wondering how to check from temp tale. You have exactly written what I want in your last logic...THanks a lot :) I will let you know how it goes further.... Cheers

Comment: I have a scenario here, where I can have a value in TableB but not in the input file (Through XML), in which case, I should make one of the column status as Inactive in the TableB. How would I write this logic?

Comment: You should start new question next time, but I will answer once here, you can use `SELECT * FROM tableB tab_b LEFT JOIN #temp tmp ON ..... WHERE tmp.ID IS NULL`. This will give you rows from tableB not existing in XML, now you can change it to update like `UPDATE tab_b SET col = 'Inactive'  FROM tableB tab_b LEFT JOIN #temp tmp ON ..... WHERE tmp.ID IS NULL`

Comment: Thank you very much, lovely, this is exactly I was looking for :) But let me construct it and I will let you know if I need any further help. Oh sure, I will create a new thread :) :) THANKS A TONNNN for helping me :) I need to report to my architect now :)

Comment: Here I have a quick question, if I want to check the field ID1 and ID2 from Table A in combination with XML parameters, I guess the same query which you wrote in comments above should work except that I replace tmp.ID IS NULL with TableA.ID = @ID1 AND TableA.ID2 = @ ID2 Is that correct?

Comment: I am concerned if it would be left join or just join. I am not able to understand its difference in this context

Comment: Quick answer, I don't know your table structure and XML so I can provide only general clues which you should always check twice yourself. Really comments are not supposed to these type of discussions. Read about [Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins). This is my last answer here.

Comment: Hi friend, sure, thanks a lot. I will read through the link. If I have any issues, I will create a new thread :) Its that before I give it to my architect, I ensure my syntax os correct :p hehe :) Thanks a lot anyway :) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I did almost the same task with parsing XML. It is very depends on XML structure. I can share my code, maybe it suits in your case.

XML:

```
<ROOT>
  <ResultOfTest Sort="2" description="Test result" is_bp_enabled="True" max_error="0.48089456118941">
    <PROPERTY Name="InputId" Description="Sample number" Value="0" Sort="1" />
    <PROPERTY Name="InputDescr" Description="Input vector description" Value="No descr" Sort="2" />
    <PROPERTY Name="OutputId" Description="Smple number" Value="0" Sort="3" />
    <PROPERTY Name="OutputDescr" Description="Output vector description" Value="No descr" Sort="4" />
    <PROPERTY Name="ErrorValue" Description="Quantitative measure of error" Value="0.291986530595333" Sort="5" />
    <PROPERTY Name="InputId" Description="Sample number" Value="1" Sort="1" />
    <PROPERTY Name="InputDescr" Description="Input vector description" Value="No descr" Sort="2" />
    <PROPERTY Name="OutputId" Description="Smple number" Value="1" Sort="3" />
    <PROPERTY Name="OutputDescr" Description="Output vector description" Value="No descr" Sort="4" />
    <PROPERTY Name="ErrorValue" Description="Quantitative measure of error" Value="0.291986527462545" Sort="5" />
    <PROPERTY Name="InputId" Description="Sample number" Value="2" Sort="1" />
    <PROPERTY Name="InputDescr" Description="Input vector description" Value="No descr" Sort="2" />
    <PROPERTY Name="OutputId" Description="Smple number" Value="2" Sort="3" />
    <PROPERTY Name="OutputDescr" Description="Output vector description" Value="No descr" Sort="4" />
    <PROPERTY Name="ErrorValue" Description="Quantitative measure of error" Value="0.292008233355948" Sort="5" />
    <PROPERTY Name="InputId" Description="Sample number" Value="3" Sort="1" />
    <PROPERTY Name="InputDescr" Description="Input vector description" Value="No descr" Sort="2" />
    <PROPERTY Name="OutputId" Description="Smple number" Value="3" Sort="3" />
    <PROPERTY Name="OutputDescr" Description="Output vector description" Value="No descr" Sort="4" />
    <PROPERTY Name="ErrorValue" Description="Quantitative measure of error" Value="0.291986537162087" Sort="5" />
  </ResultOfTest>
</ROOT>
```

My select to parse it:

```
    SELECT 
        item.value('@Name', 'varchar(100)') AS [Name],
        item.value('@Description', 'varchar(200)') AS [Description],
        item.value('@Value', 'varchar(200)') AS [Value],
        item.value('@Sort', 'varchar(10)') AS [Sort]
    FROM @i_xml.nodes('/ROOT/ResultOfTest/PROPERTY') AS t(item)
```

You could join it with your table and then insert the result into the target table.